# Deploy War on jetty Server and set config files separately

Tags: java, xml, jetty-8

I have Deployed a war file (my web project) - just by copying war file to **/webapps** in jetty folder.

(Note-> **OS - linux - centos**)

I have a mapping file/ configuration file "**abc.xml**" , and in **abc.xml** i have specified database configs and it is placed at **/WEB-INF/classes** in war file

On staging server (**jetty**), If i keep this **abc.xml** file in **/contexts** , my war still uses the file from war at **/WEB-INF/classes**.

I want to keep config (like abc.xml etc) files separately on staging server(jetty server). How can i achieve this?

Comment: Database configuration and stuff like that are intended to go in META-INF/context.xml or somewhere in WEB-INF, it would be odd to put them anywhere else in my opinion. JavaEE has a strict structure to help standardizing stuff like that.

Comment: Then can we replace xml files (config files) from war and regenerate war using commands and then deploy it on server.